# What does "The LiveArea screen has been refreshed" mean?

Tags: ps-vita

When I come back to my PS Vita occasionally it will have 1+ notifications that "The LiveArea screen has been refreshed", usually for the Videos and Store apps.

What does this mean? Does some setting control this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This indicates that the content cache powering the LiveArea UI has been refreshed. For example, when this happens, information about PSN and its available content is refreshed (amongst other things, like the video store).

Comment: And does some setting control this?

Comment: Ah. Is there some way to turn off the notification?

Comment: @BenBrocka - Not as far as I'm aware, but that's with the caveat that I don't actually own the device in question to look for myself.

Comment: @BenBrocka at least with the latest firmware update (1.8) that notification is far less annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It means that something may have been updated or added to the playstation store but this may only occur when it has the playstation store icon in the corner. If it has the video Icon when it says live area has been refreshed then I'm not too sure. Because it just said it now and when I clicked it, it showed a new game was added to the ps store on my vita.